# Calling a c# COM dll from vba

Tags: c#, vba, dll, ms-word, com

I have created a class library that contains a form where the user can pick a choose items from a database. I want to be able to run this dll from vba within word, via a button on the ribbon.

So far I have created windows form and it works as expected when built as a windows application. When built as a class library and the dll is referenced within a WordAddin project, it works as expected. The issue occurs when I attempt to run the dll form from the vba code.

I have added the ddl as a reference and ensured that the class library is Com Visible (Properties > Build > Register for COM interop, Assembly Information > Make assembly COM-Visible and [ComVisible(true)] above the class). I have also strongly signed the project and registered without error with regAsm.exe /codebase "ddl path".

Below is the vba code that is attempting to open the form. The code errors on oForm1.ShowDialog line with the error: Automation error.

```
Public Sub TimecardLookup()
    Dim oForm1 As New GeldardsTimecardLookup.Form1
    oForm1.ShowDialog

    Dim a As String
    a = oForm1.outputText

    ActiveDocument.Application.Selection.Range.Text = a
End Sub
```

I presume I am missing a setting in my dll, I have [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)] enabled also, to allow for intellisense. All the class library does is show a dialog, read from a SQL database via Entity Framework and returns a string.

Comment: what is the error? where is the type library?

Comment: @cyboashu The error occurs in the vba code at oForm1.ShowDialog.
Error message is: Run-time error '-2146233079 (80131509)' Automation error. I am not sure what this error means but it seems generic. The tlb file is in the same folder as the dll file.

Comment: in your regasm use /tlb switch too....

Comment: @cyboashu tried: regasm my.dll /tlb:my.tlb and it successfully ran but the same error occurs.

Comment: @cyboashu I had a long list of "Type library exporter warnings .... Warning: Non Com visible value type 'System....' is being referenced either from the type currently being exported or from one of its base types". But the last message says that the assembly has exported successfully.

Answer (score 3):

> Run-time error '-2146233079 (80131509)' Automation error.

8013 says that this error was caused by a .NET exception.  1509 says that it was an InvalidOperationException.  No reason to assume that this has anything to do with the way you built or registered your project.  Managed exceptions don't exactly get easier to troubleshoot when it is a native app that reports them, you for one can't get the holy stack trace to tell you where it died.

You'll have to use the debugger to find the cause.  Project > Properties > Debug tab > select "Start external program" and select the Office app executable, WinWord.exe in this case.  Use Debug > Exceptions and tick the Thrown checkbox for CLR exceptions so that the debugger stops when the exception is thrown.  Press F5.  If you can't get a debugger onto the machine that fails then use the DebugDiag utility.

Comment: Doing this located the error for me, Thanks. The error is "No connection string named 'myEntities' could be found in the application config file. The app config of the dll has the connection, so does this mean that the config of MS Word requires it?

Comment: DLLs cannot have a config file, only the EXE.  You can write a winword.exe.config file and put it in the same directory as winword.exe.  It is however brittle if other people are likely to write add-ins.

Comment: @HansPassant thanks, would it be possible to create a myproject.dll.config file and store the EF connection information in here? as adding a config to winword would be in a different directory as my dll, so would be annoying to maintain? many thanks

Comment: @HansPassant: Is there any place where the numbering scheme of HRESULT values is documented? [This](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/__hresults.cs.html) was as close as I could get, but it seems not like an official documentation.

Comment: Yes, the WinError.h SDK include file.  .NET specific error codes (like 1509) are in CorError.h